# Batch file to delete files older than N days and save the result as a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am able to create a bacth file to delete files older than n days but i am having problem with saving the deletion results. What i want is listing the deletion result in a text file after the process.

I have tried this code below. It works and delete all files. It also creates result.txt but the txt file is empty. I am seeing that files are being deleted. Any idea why they are not being saved in the text file?

```
forfiles -p "C:\Log\" -s -m *.* /D -1 /C "cmd /c del @path" >> "c:\result.txt"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will provide a log of files that have been used with the del command, but not a confirmed result.
If a file is read only for example then it will still exist.

```
 forfiles -p "C:\Log\" -s -m *.* /D -1 /C "cmd /c del @path & echo @path >>c:\result.txt"
```